# EC2 How to use private ip when using domain name?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

I read you incur cost if one of your ec2 accesses another ec2 with public ip (going through internet) You can avoid that cost by using private ip.

So I want them to use private ip. Furthermore, I want to use domain name to access other ec2s (such as `foo.example.com`)

Currently I have `foo.example.com` : `{some-public-ip}` in my DNS

How can I change this so that I can use `foo.example.com:5432` and it uses private ip?

There's one more constraint: I want `www.example.com` (ec2-based ECS) to connect to `foo.example.com:5432` and want to prevent access to `foo.example.com` from public internet. (only allow access from www's security group)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing stops you from setting the DNS record for `foo.example.com` to the instance *Private IP*. Especially as you don't need to have it accessible from outside you don't need its *Public IP* in the DNS.

Alternatively you can have two DNS records: `foo-private.example.com` with private IP and `foo.example.com` with public IP.

The point is that you can have the private IP in DNS.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution,

you put `ec2-***.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com` as a cname for `foo.example.com`

["We resolve a public DNS hostname to the public IPv4 address of the instance outside the network of the instance, and to the private IPv4 address of the instance from within the network of the instance."](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-hostnames)

Comment: This is correct, though not necessarily intuitive unless you are familiar with this feature of the VPC resolver. If you want `foo.example.com` to resolve to the machine's private IP from inside the VPC but to its public IP from outside, this is how you do it -- a CNAME pointing to the *public* hostname.  [*"We resolve a public DNS hostname to the public IPv4 address of the instance outside the network of the instance, and to the private IPv4 address of the instance from within the network of the instance."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-hostnames)

Comment: Your answer ideally should explain this, for the benefit of future visitors.

Comment: added to the answer thanks @Michael-sqlbot

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use vpc-dns for instead of private ip.But your instances have to be in the same vpc.
Check the following link 
[VPC-DNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html)

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually do it is that I put the private IP in the hosts file inside the machine that will access the other one.

I also do the same to any domains that reference the machine itself to avoid it going to the internet instead of using localhost.